# Target the last word within an <h1> element

Tags: jquery

Does anybody know whether this can be achieved in jQuery. Target/addClass to the last word of an element, in this case the word 'Text' within a h1 tag. Bear in mind I know I can target the last word with a span tag but I'm working with a CMS that has something like %My_heading% markup. (not exactly but I'm hoping this is understood)

```
<h1>Some Heading Text</h1>
```

Comment: What does it mean _addClass to the last word_ ? Do you want to wrap last word of that element in another element? like `<h1>Some Heading <span>Text</span></h1>` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    $('h1').html(function(index, curHTML) {
       var text = curHTML.split(/[\s-]/),
           newtext = '<span class="some">' + text.pop() + '</span>';
       return text.join(' ').concat(' ' + newtext);
     });
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to add class to the last word, you anyway need to surround it with a tag.

One of the easiest ways to do it is using regular expression:

```
$("h1").html(function(index, old) {
    return old.replace(/(\b\w+)$/, '<span class="myClass">$1</span>');
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Dy4vh/

Comment: Well that worked - thanks heaps! I know you can do this <h1>Some Heading <span class='someclass'>Text</span></h1> but when you're working with a content management system CMS it's not always easy.

Comment: Hey! it is working perfectly as long as we do not have diacritics if we have any diacritics id desnțt work , some ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
//Split the string into words
var last_arr = $('h1').text().split(' ');
//Get the last one
var last = last_arr[last_arr.length - 1];
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/KZFX4/

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
var txt = $("h1").text();
var splitted = txt.split(" ");
var lastWord = splitted.pop();
var newTxt = splitted.join(" ") + "<span class='someclass'> " + lastWord + "</span>";
console.log(newTxt);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qUb6/

Comment: Thank you, your logic makes sense - would you be kind enough to update the jsFiddle so I can see it working?